# Return window object using puppeteer

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping, chromium, puppeteer

I'm trying to return the whole windows object from a page, and then traversing the object outside of puppeteer.

I'm trying to access the data in Highcharts property, for which I need to access the window object. The normal javascript code being something like `window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data`.

I thought the easiest way would be to use puppeteer to access the site, and just send me back the windows object, which I could then use outside of puppeteer like any other JS object.

After reading the documentation, I'm finding it difficult to return the object as it would appear just putting 'window' into the chrome console. I'm not sure what I'm missing?

I've read through the documentation, and the following two methods seem like they should work?

```
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.example.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

    // METHOD 1
    // Create a Map object
    await page.evaluate(() => window.map = new Map());
    // Get a handle to the Map object prototype
    const mapPrototype = await page.evaluateHandle(() => Map.prototype);
    // Query all map instances into an array
    const mapInstances = await page.queryObjects(mapPrototype);

    console.log(mapInstances);

    await mapInstances.dispose();
    await mapPrototype.dispose();

    // METHOD 2
    const handle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => ({window, document}));
    const properties = await handle.getProperties();
    const windowHandle = properties.get('window');
    const documentHandle = properties.get('document');
    var result = await page.evaluate(win => win, windowHandle);

    console.log(result)

    await handle.dispose();



    await browser.close();
})();
```

However, it only returns the following in the console, and not the simple object I would like;

[image]

Not sure if I'm going about this the right way, so any help/advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

"Return the window to Node" is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). It's impossible to return the window because it's a complex, non-serializable, massive data structure that has circular references. Puppeteer basically calls `JSON.stringify(window)` when you try to return it from `evaluate()`, and this doesn't work in any browser I know of.

If you're trying to pull data from an object that happens to be attached to the window, you can do that in the browser, then return the small serializable subset of the window that you care about back to Node. Here's a proof of concept:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.0.2

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  window.Highcharts = {
    charts: [{series: [{data: "hello world"}]}]
  };
}, 3000); // add the variable sometime after page load
</script>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  const data = await page.evaluate(`
    window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data
  `);
  console.log(data); // => hello world
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Let's say this data isn't available on the page load. You can block until it's ready by waiting for a certain element to appear with `waitForElement`, or wait for the variable directly with `waitForFunction`:

```js
const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script>
setTimeout(() => {
  window.Highcharts = {
    charts: [{series: [{data: "hello world"}]}]
  };
}, 3000); // add the variable sometime after page load
</script>
</body></html>`;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.setContent(html);
  await page.waitForFunction(`
    window?.Highcharts?.charts[0]?.series[0]?.data
  `);
  const data = await page.evaluate(`
    window.Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].data
  `);
  console.log(data); // => hello world
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had a timing issue since Puppeteer interacts asynchronously with the page. Adding a waitForFunction to the page worked for me.

```
await page.waitForFunction(() => window.objectOnMyWindow !== undefined);
const objectOnMyWindow = await page.evaluate(() => window.objectOnMyWindow);
```